# Pixelated video playback in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, video, 64-bit, video-codecs

I am using Windows 7 64 bit with ATI Radeon 5730 graphics in my laptop. I get pixelated video playback or in some cases problems with sound. Here are the combinations I tried.

1. K-lite Mega Codec 32 bit + Media Player Classic Home Cinema 32 bit
2. K-lite Mega Codec 64 bit + Media Player Classic Home Cinema 64 bit
3. Shark007 Windows 7 Codec + x64 components (suggested settings) + Media Player Classic Home Cinema 64 bit
4. VLC Media player 1.1.5
5. GOM Player
6. Shark007 Windows 7 Codec + x64 components (suggested settings) + Windows Media Player (32 bit or 64 bit)

Out of all these I got best results only with #6 i.e. Shark007 Windows 7 Codec + x64 components (suggested settings) + Windows Media Player. The same video works perfectly in 32bit Windows 7. Is #6 the only option ?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that, if you run Win 7 x86 on that particular machine, the vids look fine, but if you run Win 7 x64 on that particular machine, they look pixelated? Because if you're talking about two different machines, the architecture may have nothing to do with the problem whatsoever.